# Language change is not reflected immediately for all strings

Tags: android, localization, android-framework

Am working on android framework level. When I change the language from "Settings" -> "Language & keyboard settings" -> "Select Locale"(or "Select Language") then our Launcher and Apps not change the language dynamically. But when we reboot the device then that changes will be reflected. Any one have any idea about this problem?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

This is a base android issue. The issue is also seen in Lock Screen. What lock screen code does is, it stores the string in an array in the constructor. This array is never refreshed after the locale change intent is triggered. In other words, they are not doing the setText() by fetching the string from strings.xml, rather they fetch it from that array and set it. Hope this helps to debug the issue.